# using google classroom api to change course ownerId

Tags: google-classroom

How? Easiest method?

Tried using postman on desktop, googles OAuth2 playground and google help pages to try make sense of what to do. Ended up using *GAM* as this is the easiest and gives the most helpful responses.

I have tried changing this from multiple places and i always get the error:

> ERROR: 400: @UserInIllegalDomain Invitation cannot be created for user in this domain - failedPrecondition

the command:

`gam update course 8077159861 owner hiddenusername@longleypark.ac.uk`

(username is DEFINITELY correct ive just hidden it as its not vital information)

Any help would be much appreciated, from what i can tell some guides said to add longleypark.ac.uk to whitelisted domain under classroom but because this is the primary domain for this g suite it says you cant add your current domain so this isnt an option.

I believe the google API is broken. If anyone can prove otherwise would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Google API support haven't managed to give me any proper response, keep saying they will test and let me know but I haven't been informed of any results yet.

Google forums support has informed me once a user account is deleted and 20 days have passed the account becomes unrecoverable which means any classrooms they are the owner of become "orphans" which means "limited functionality" and the inability to change the owner ever again, the only solution is to recreate the classroom from scratch, unfortunately along with the original account all the documents submitted to that classroom are also lost.

There are **NO** ways around this even though the ownerId field for a classroom really should be editable from some sort of database management tool or admin console/API.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem today. Thought using the API I'd be able to swap the `ownerId`, but no.

Bizarre that Google don't let you do this as a Google Workspace admin. We know have 3 GCSE sets which are unusable with 3 months of the 2 year course left. Very frustrating.